# How do I get a user input and insert it into the api link is JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, api

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  body, html {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: Arial 14px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
  Enter GD Username:
</p>
<input id="bruh">
<script>      
  var bruh = document.getElementById("bruh").value;
  const url = `https://example.com/api/${bruh}`;
  async function getData() {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
}
</script>
<button onclick="getData()">
Try
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Hey guys, right now I’m trying hard to make a system that can fetch data from an api from what the user types in. What I have done already is make the fetching work, and the variable works, but for some reason when I type in something in the input box, it doesn’t work. Anyone know why?

Comment: Your getData() is a function. Should cover the whole script under a function name getData();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you click the button the bruh variable is already declared but not defined. so You need to have these 2 lines inside your function:

```
var bruh = document.getElementById("bruh").value;   
const url = `https://example.com/api/${bruh}`;
```

So you final code should look like this:

```
<script>      
  
async function getData() {
  var bruh = document.getElementById("bruh").value;
  const url = `https://example.com/api/${bruh}`;
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
}
</script>
```

Comment: More specifically, the value of the variable `bruh` is evaluated only once on page load in the OPs example. This approach ensures that the value is retrieved every time `getData()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're getting the input value as soon as the DOM/website is loaded and it means that it's going to be empty. You have to get the input value inside the getData function when you press click.

Answer (score 0):

Change the script to this:

```
<script> 
    async function getData() { 
        var bruh = document.getElementById("bruh").value;
        const url = `https://example.com/api/${bruh}`;
        const response = await fetch(url); 
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
    }
</script>
```

Every time you click the button the variable bruh need to be updated, thus the need to be inside the function. Otherwise every time you click it will send the same request as before.